# what is the point of queryBuilder.appendWhere()? android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

what's the point here to use  `queryBuilder.appendWhere()`? isn't it much simpler to set the where clause in `Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query()`? or the two ways to set the "where" clause are different from each other?

```
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    // Check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
    checkColumns(projection);

    // Set the table
    queryBuilder.setTables(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO);

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      // Adding the ID to the original query
      queryBuilder.appendWhere(TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
          + uri.getLastPathSegment());
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    // Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return cursor;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `appendWhere()` if you are building up the pieces of a `WHERE` clause based on conditions.